# Why don't I see a transform activity in my eclipse helios bpel process manager

Tags: eclipse, bpel

I am using eciipse helios. I want to create a bpel transform like in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_xslt_mpr.htm#CFACBIEC) tutorial. But I don't see a transform activity in the "Actions" section or the "Control 2" section of my palette. What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you linked is from Oracle and the IDE they provide is JDeveloper. Eclipse is not JDeveloper, so you don't have the same palettes. You will have to [download JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html), if you want to replicate the tutorial.

I assume (from the link) that you want to write an XSL transformation. You can also do this with Eclipse. [The Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) which is included in the Java EE version of Eclipse, comes with support for writing XSL transformations.

Comment: @joegrl do you know a good tutorial on transforms with the web tools platform?

Comment: @akh2013: I can recommend the tutorials from Lars Vogel, he also has one on [XSLT with Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/XSLT/article.html). This one is very basic, but it should get you started. Good tutorials on XSL are provided by the [w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/)

Comment: thanks for the help. I am assuming that this tutorial will also help me answer this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123473/i-have-two-web-services-with-two-complex-types-with-identical-structures-and-a-d right?

Comment: Yes, this should help. You can write an XSL transformation and then use it in an `assign` activity. This should look somewhat like: `<from>bpel:doXslTransform("copy.xslt", $personalInfoServiceOutput.parameters)</from><to>$positionSkillManagementInput.parameters</to>`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the BPEL 2.0 specification does not define such an activity. It is a proprietary extension defined by Oracle, thus it is only available in Oracle products. The open source Eclipse BPEL projects aims at providing support for the BPEL standard only.